# When will the dash be implimented in Natty development?

Tags: unity, 11.04

I am currently using Natty 11.04, at updating daily. I was just wondering when the dash will be implimented, as there are some really neat feature (like zeitgeist, etc.) that I'd really like to try out and post bug reports for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't currently find a source for this, but I remember hearing that we would see the Dash in time for **Alpha 2**. If you look at the [Natty Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyReleaseSchedule) then that puts us at early February.

Comment: That you very much, though I will wait for official confirmatin/date before calling this "Answered"

Comment: Alpha 2 is indeed the current target. Note that that's the deadline, so parts of it could start landing before.